# How can I import `less` from an ES Module?

Tags: node.js, less, es6-modules

I need to import `less` module from an ES6-module.

```
import less = require('less');
```

And I expected the constant `less` will be the `default` export of `less` module(`exports.default = ...`). However it was just an object that contains `default` field.

So I had to use it as `less.default.render(...)`.
And It causes error markers due to @types/d.ts and TypeScript type system even it runs correct.

What did I miss?

Thanks.

Comment: I realized that I did not set `esModuleInterop` flag.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop